# unable to install winkerberos or pykerberos

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kerberos, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am working on a python script. In the script I am running a powershell script using ntlm. I cannot use ntlm for production and kerberos is required.I am not able to install pykerberos or winkerberos.

winkerberos

```
    Collecting winkerberos
  Using cached winkerberos-0.9.1.zip (43 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: winkerberos
  Building wheel for winkerberos (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for winkerberos (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'winkerberos' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for winkerberos
Failed to build winkerberos
ERROR: Could not build wheels for winkerberos, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

pykerberos

```
Collecting pykerberos
  Using cached pykerberos-1.2.4.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pykerberos
  Building wheel for pykerberos (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pykerberos (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'kerberos' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pykerberos
Failed to build pykerberos
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pykerberos, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. - I intalled this to fix the issue but still for winkerberos I am getting this. I was getting this error for pykerberos as well but after installation it doesn't show this error.

This is how I am connecting to winrm:

```
sess = winrm.Session(
        remote_host,
        auth=(remote_username, remote_password),
            #server_cert_validation='ignore',
            transport='ntlm'
        )
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: I am using python 3.12

Comment: I have `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater`, I was able to install `Installing collected packages: winkerberos
Successfully installed winkerberos-0.9.1`.... I am also using `python 3.12`. My OS is `Windows 11`.

Comment: Have you considered avoiding these packages entirely and using the more modern `pyspnego` instead? That's what both python-pypsrp and python-winrm already use for PowerShell remoting.

Comment: I am using **windows 10** in the lab environment as of now. I will have a check on **pyspnego**.

Comment: pyspnego installed, but I'm not able to import it. error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspnego'

Comment: The import is just "spnego", like the docs show. (It's one of those cases where the pip name doesn't match the import because the pip name was already taken.) But, can you provide more details about how you're doing WinRM exactly? Are you trying to do it by hand, not using either of the two existing WinRM modules?

Comment: Updated the connection part on the main question.